# Can I remove unnecessary items from Coderush menus?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ide, devexpress, coderush

When you call Coderush to refactor something, sometimes it pulls options altogether with those that we already got in VS by default, like here in the picture.

[image: CodeRush Refactor menu]

That kinda bothers me. Is it possible to remove VS stuff and keep only that belongs to CodeRush?

Coderush 10.2.5 
Visual Studio 2010

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand it properly, you have installed CodeRush Xpress and Refactor.  If you want to remove the VS refactoring menu, uninstall the CodeRush Xpress and leave Refactor.  If you have CodeRush installed, it should stay installed, too.

Comment: If you have the CodeRush installed, you won't loose anything.